# Include redirect in URL link so I can link to another site?

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

Frustrating situation. Using a WordPress theme from a site I took over recently. Problem is all the URLs in the nav menu start with the domain name of the site by default. So if I want to link to Instagram, let's say, I can't because `www.instagram.com/yourprofile` becomes `www.example.com/www.instagram.com/yourprofile` which won't work.

So is there some kind of way I can make it where I can do a link that starts with a URL and then redirects over to another site?

Comment: Wouldn’t you rather want to change the URLs in the menu?

Comment: That's the problem. I can't. If I add the URL I want, it adds the site URL to the front of it, making it invalid.

Comment: What I meant is: Instead of asking how to circumvent this with a "hack" like redirecting, why don’t you ask how to change the URLs? (this would require more insight, e.g. relevant code examples)

Comment: That's just it. I don't have any code examples. All I can do is redirect.